# PHP Laravel Query Cloning Not Working as Expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I'm coming across an issue with `QueryBuilder` cloning. He's my situation, I need to run 3 separate queries, all based off a single "BaseQuery":

```
$baseQuery = $model->selectRaw("column")->whereNull("deleted_at");

$query1 = clone($baseQuery);
$query1Results = $query1->where("condition", "=", 0)->get();

$query2 = clone($baseQuery);
$query2Results = $query2->where("condition2", "=", 1)->get();

$query3 = clone($baseQuery);
$query3Results = $query3->where("condition3", "=", 0)->get();
```

By the time I get to `$query3`, it has 3 where statements. Substituting `$query3 ... get()` with `$query3 ... ->toSql();` shows these results:

```
SELECT `column` FROM `models` WHERE `deleted_at` IS NULL AND `condition` = ? AND `condition2` = ? AND `condition3` = ?;
```

It seems that even though I am defining each `$queryX` as a clone of `$baseQuery`, the additional `->where()` clause is being applied to each of the queries. I've tried doing the `clone()` before appending any of the `->where()` clauses, but that doesn't have any affect.

Is there a way to `clone()` something and ensure that it creates a new instance? It looks like `clone()` isn't separating `$baseQuery` from `$queryX`, so the `->where()`s are being applied to every subsequent copy, even though each *should* be a new query with only the `->whereNull()` clause.

Another interesting point is that running

```
\Log::info($baseQuery == $queryX);
```

After each modification returns `true` (`===` is `false` though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes) here.

> Local scopes allow you to define common sets of constraints that you may easily re-use throughout your application. For example, you may need to frequently retrieve all users that are considered "popular". To define a scope, simply prefix an Eloquent model method with  scope

```
public function scopeBase($q)
{
    return $q->selectRaw('column')->whereNull('deleted_at');
}
```

Then just do something like this:

```
$query1Results = $model->where('condition', 0)->base()->get();
$query2Results = $model->where('condition2', 1)->base()->get();
$query3Results = $model->where('condition3', 0)->base()->get();
```

Comment: That did it; Wasn't familiar with the `scope` functionality of the `QueryBuilder`, will definitely keep this in mind for future use cases.